# DefaultValue for designer

Tags: c#, forms

I have :

```
public partial class TableForm : Form
{
    [DefaultValue( "author" )]
    public string tableName;

    public TableForm( string tableName )
    {
        this.tableName = tableName;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

But in method `InitializeComponent()` error at line :

```
    ...
    this.dataGridView.DataMember = this.tableName;
    ...
```

Error only in the form's designer, program works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean *"error in the form's designer"* and not just *"in form constructor"*?
If so, try to create a private parameterless constructor for your form:

```
private TableForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```